# How to solve "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when I tried passing variable from php to js?

Tags: javascript, php

**PHP**

```
<?php $arr = array(); $i = 0; $arr[0] = 'desk'; $arr[1] = 'chair'; $arr[2] = 'carpet'; ?>
```

**JS**

```
var test = "<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>";
console.log(test[0]);
```

When I inspect and check on console tab, I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error. And when I check in sources tab, the error lead to a code statement as shown in the image below. What did I do wrong? Currently I'm using laravel 5.4.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to get rid of the double quote around your PHP.

Saying like this:

```
var test = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>
```

This will result in:

```
var test = ["desk","chair","carpet"];
```

Comment: straight forward answer, tqvm

Answer (score 3):

Please, never do that unless you want people to inject arbitrary codes into your site.

JavaScript source codes should never be generated. Create an API endpoint or some other information passing mechanism instead.

Comment: not really what he's asking though. This should be a comment :\

Comment: @TreeNguyen This isn't really a comment. The solution for not getting a syntax error is to not do that in the first place. I have listed out the alternatives in which OP can choose and implement it himself.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is surrounded by quotes. In js array declarations are not surrounded by quotes. You may need to modify the output of the json encoding or pass a flag to tell it to not surround the output in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use non-associative array, you can force it to be an object using the predefined constant [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://Force%20it%20to%20be%20an%20object)

```
var test = "<?php echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>";
```